# CodeFirst select the property to be displayed inside an Html.DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following models (simplified) used inside a CodeFirst scaffolded ASP.NET MVC site:

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid ID {get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Display(Name = "Order Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public Guid OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

`Order` doesn't contain a string property, so in the Edit view of OrderLine the GUID is displayed inside the dropdown, but I want to display the `Number` property instead

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderID, "Order Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("OrderID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

It's possible to define at model level which property should be considered to be displayed inside the dropdown or which is the syntax for the DropDownList helper to specify the text in this scenario?

Comment: **Which is syntax for the DropDownList?** [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx) is the link that contains various overloaded method from msdn

Comment: do you mind to write an example that actually works in my case?

Answer (score 2):

> It's possible to define at model level which property should be considered to be displayed inside the dropdown

You can create instance of `SelectList` and passed it to `DropDownList` method of `Html` Helper class as follows:

```
ViewBag.Orders = new SelectList(db.Orders // select Orders from databse here
              , "OrderID" // value property inside the order class
              , "Name");  // display text property in the dropdown
```

and use it in view like below

```
@Html.DropDownList("OrderID", ViewBag.Orders as SelectList,  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" });
```

Comment: there isn't another way? really I need to put all the elements inside the ViewBag just for this?

Comment: @user35912 You may pass it along with model. Any ways there is few more ways to pass data between view to controller refer this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/)